# Is there a way to test an individual Monit control file?

Tags: monit

I've created a Monit control file, but it doesn't seem to be working. It would be nice to have a way to test Monitor control files other than by just letting them run and seeing if they work. Anyone have any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several levels at which one could "test Monitor control files," the lowest level of which is validating that everything about it is syntactically correct. Have you started with the validation check?

```
monit -t -c <path_to_control_file>/monitrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile since I used this product but isn't there an http port that monit provides (or can be configured) that you can use a web browser to look at this type of thing?